# Sharing different repositories between jobs for Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In our project we have a number of repositories that are all needed to build a few different docker containers.

The Dockerfiles of all containers are located in a single repository.

I would like to be able to pull all repositories I need for the builds before building the containers. This would avoid pulling a repository multiple times which can take almost a minute for some of these.

Essentially what I would like to do is:

```
stages:
  - initialize
  - build

repo1 pull:
  stage: initialize
  script:
    - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.instance/group/repo1.git

repo2 pull:
  stage: initialize
  script:
    - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.instance/group/repo2.git

image1:
  stage: build
  script:
      - cp repo1/ image1/
      - cd image1
      - docker build -t image1 --network=host .
      - docker login -u gitlab-runner -p gitlab docker.registry
      - docker push docker.registry/image1:latest

image2:
  stage: build
  script:
      - cp repo2/ image2/
      - cd image2
      - docker build -t image2 --network=host .
      - docker login -u gitlab-runner -p gitlab docker.registry
      - docker push docker.registry/image2:latest
```

What is the best way to share the repositories over the stages while still allowing for parallel building within the stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still learning Gitlab-ci but maybe `cache` would help?

Add this before you pull the repos and the runner should check if the repo is already in the cache.

```
cache:
  paths:
    - repo1/
    - repo2/
```

Gitlab cache reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/

Edit:
Or maybe using Git submodules for the dependant repos would be a good idea?
The runner can then be configured to fetch those submodules to the workspace and you should have access to them throughout the ci job.

You need to add a `.gitmodules` file that would looks something like this:

```
[submodule "repo1"]
  path = repo1
  url = ../repo1.git
[submodule "repo2"]
  path = repo2
  url = ../repo2.git
```

And then in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
 variables:
   GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: normal
```

Gitlab submodule reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/git_submodules.html

Comment: The submodules strategy looks rather good so I tried it out but I am hitting issues. I added the .gitmodules file like you indicated and put the Strategy in as well. When looking at the output it says that it is removing the submodule folder. If I run `ls` as a script the submodule is indeed not there anymore. 

Any idea what I am doing wrong there?

Comment: Update, it is not actually removing the submodule, but it seems it is not fetched at all. I get the line "Updating/initializing submodules..." but when running `ls` the submodule is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: Update: I used the actual git command to add the submodule, which made it work correctly! Thanks for the idea.